# What's the advantage of branching program? Why we use branching program to compute the encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

Branching program is one type of NC1 circuit and can be used to compute encrypted data. So whether there exist other methods in the NC1 circuit to compute encrypted data. What's the advantage of branching program? Why we use branching program to compute the encrypted data?

I attached some related papers as follows:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.182.4237&rep=rep1&type=pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/267.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/541.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/339.pdf

Comment: Hi! I have already seen people using branching programs to obfuscate programs... Could you please provide some links to works that use it to compute over encrypted data?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://f56eaedc-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/anatpaschern/home/files/bptcc.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crpd_xebBrXYHzYywuRPX9O8MospHWvMiwvxb41FuB3AsybAEOYwoOd8PBLf4GoIIAh5d9d4bv5h_sFPBsVU6VZr43KVqHGalOXI6SZsIT50ZIV34MkpdNfIfKBUVBYeI9AdpK4LubTuO1ZrYAUPQ_yjqG8GIK7dBdUh9Nev9vTxUFJ-USGi4uaAQgMlDY2TniMhOjHUeWiJxgi4B5Df-UNe8mXWLwjZkedcA989UkdDwyamh0%3D&attredirects=0) paper? If so, I think the answer is that no one does it like that any more.